# D3.js zoomable axis- how to zoom in only one direction?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js v4.

I have a minimum example working with zooming in and out on a single axis, with the following code:

```
// Create dummy data
var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push([Math.random(), Math.random()]);
  }
// Set window parameters
var width = 330
var height = 200

  // Append div, svg
  d3.select('body').append('div')
    .attr('id', 'div1')
  d3.select('#div1')
  .append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height",height)
    .attr('id','chart')

// Create scaling factors
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,1])
            .range([0, (width - 30)])

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,1])
            .range([0,height])

  // Create group, then append circles
  d3.select('#chart').append('g')
    .attr('id','circlesplot')

  d3.select('#circlesplot')
    .selectAll('circles')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i){ return x(d[0]); })
    .attr('cy', function(d,i){ return y(d[1]); })
    .attr('r', 4)

// Create y axis, append to chart
  var yaxis = d3.axisRight(y)
                .ticks(10)

  var yaxis_g = d3.select('#chart').append('g')
                    .attr('id', 'yaxis_g')
                    .attr('transform','translate(' + (width - 30) +',0)')
                    .call(yaxis)

  // Create zoom svg to the right
  var svg = d3.select('#div1')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', 30)
                .attr('height', height)
                .attr('transform', 'translate('+ width + ',0)')
                .call(d3.zoom()
                        .on('zoom', zoom))

  function zoom() {
    // Rescale axis during zoom
    yaxis_g.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .call(yaxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)))

    // re-draw circles using new y-axis scale
      var new_y = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

      d3.selectAll('circle').attr('cy', function(d) { return new_y(d[1])})
  }
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v0aw9Ler/#&togetherjs=2wg7s8xfhC

Putting the mouse just to the right of the yaxis and scrolling gives the zooming function on the y axis.

What I'd like to happen is for the y axis maximum (in this case 1.0) to stay fixed, while zooming only in the other direction. You can kind of see what I mean by placing the mouse at the very bottom and just to the right of the y axis, and see the points cluster at the bottom  of the graph.

I think it has to do with using zoom.extent(), but I'm just really not sure where to go from here; advice is greatly appreciated.

Source for this min working example:
http://bl.ocks.org/feyderm/03602b83146d69b1b6993e5f98123175

Comment: I can help you with this, but your jsfiddle isn't zooming in chrome. Can you check?

Comment: @inspired I can zoom in Chrome. You have to put your mouse to the right of the y axis and wheel scroll though.